# How does a LINQ expression know that Where() comes before Select()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to create a LINQ provider. I'm using the guide *[LINQ: Building an IQueryable provider series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2008/11/18/linq-links.aspx)*, and I have added the code up to LINQ: Building an IQueryable Provider - Part IV.

I am getting a feel of how it is working and the idea behind it. Now I'm stuck on a problem, which isn't a code problem but more about the understanding.

I'm firing off this statement:

```
QueryProvider provider = new DbQueryProvider();
Query<Customer> customers = new Query<Customer>(provider);

int i = 3;
var newLinqCustomer = customers.Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Name}).Where(p => p.Id == 2 | p.Id == i).ToList();
```

Somehow the code, or expression, knows that the `Where` comes before the `Select`. But how and where?

There is no way in the code that sorts the expression, in fact the `ToString()` in debug mode, shows that the Select comes before the `Where`.

I was trying to make the code fail. Normal I did the `Where` first and then the `Select`.

So how does the expression sort this? I have not done any change to the code in the guide.

Comment: What do you mean “where comes before the select”? You mean in the generated SQL?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that maybe you're seeing the generated SQL has the SELECT and WHERE reordered? In which case I'd guess that there's an optimisation step somewhere in the Linq2Sql provider that takes `SELECT Id, Name FROM (SELECT Id, Name FROM Customer WHERE Id=2 || Id=@i)` and converts it to `SELECT Id, Name FROM Customer WHERE Id=2 || Id=@i` - but is this what you're seeing and is it what you are asking?

Comment: You know of [re-linq](http://relinq.codeplex.com/), right? You aren't reinventing the wheel I hope :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expressions are "interpreted", "translated" or "executed" in the order you write them - so the `Where` does **not** come before the `Select`

---

If you execute:

```
        var newLinqCustomer = customers.Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Name})
                                       .Where(p => p.Id == 2 | p.Id == i).ToList();
```

Then the `Where` is executed on the `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` of the anonymous type.

---

If you execute:

```
        var newLinqCustomer = customers.Where(p => p.Id == 2 | p.Id == i)
                                       .Select(c => new { c.Id, c.Name}).ToList();
```

Then the `Where` is executed on the `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable` of the customer type.

---

The only thing I can think of is that maybe you're seeing some generated SQL where the SELECT and WHERE have been reordered? In which case I'd guess that there's an optimisation step somewhere in the (e.g.) [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL) provider that takes `SELECT Id, Name FROM (SELECT Id, Name FROM Customer WHERE Id=2 || Id=@i)` and converts it to `SELECT Id, Name FROM Customer WHERE Id=2 || Id=@i` - but this must be a provider specific optimisation.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. What's the different between “executed on IQueryable” and “executed in LinqToSQL”?

Comment: Sorry - tidied it up now. As I said in my comment on the question, I can only imagine the OP is seeing some optimisation performed in whichever linq provider he is currently looking at - but we don't have that detail from his question.

Comment: If the select filter i fired before the where, I must be enable to see it in the code, by a break-point, but I cant. 
You say that, if I do the select first,then the where is do on the anonymous type, but there is no method call with the name Select how can that be ?     I

Comment: For Linq2Objects I think you might be able to see the filter executed using breakpoints. For Linq2Sql, however, the filter isn't executed in code but instead is converted to Sql - so a breakpoint won't work.

Comment: Sorry - not sure I understand your question about "no method call with the name Select how can that be? I" - did it get cut short?

Comment: I dont know how I else can descibe it, but his code call at some point protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m) , in this section he checks if it is a select call or where call. If i run from g ...).Select, it runs the where call, It seems like I never come into the select.

Comment: If you have the source, then your gut instincts are right - it must call into the Select... it must - try without the Where initially to make sure you get your breakpoint/understanding correct. (Sorry - this is really hard to debug when I'm not quite sure which project you're currently looking at - I'm assuming your looking at a project including the output of Matt Warren's blog?)

Comment: That is correct, im looking at the project from Matt Warren, sry if I wan'st 100% clear on that part. I have removed the where, so I only have the select-part, Now im hitting my break point, if I add the where-part again, im not hitting the select. Why is that ?

Answer (score 4):

No, in the general case (such as [LINQ to Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_Objects)) the select will be executed before the where statement. Think of it is a pipeline, your first step is a transformation, the second a filter. Not the other way round, as it would be the case if you wrote Where...Select.

Now, a LINQ Provider has the freedom to walk the expression tree and optimize it as it sees fit. Be aware that you may not change the semantics of the expression though. This means that a smart [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL) provider would try to pull as many `where` clauses it can into the SQL query to reduce the amount of data travelling over the network. However, keep [the example from Stuart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801963/how-does-linq-expression-know-that-where-comes-before-select/6802850#6802850) in mind: Not all query providers are clever, partly because ruling out side effects from query reordering is not as easy as it seems.

Comment: I don't think that your first paragraph is correct. The `Select` and `Where` clauses are just projections and filters and, to preserve semantics, they must occur in the order given. There's no "general case" that one occurs before the other. It's in whatever order that the original query was written in.