# Linq query - Tidy Up/Optimization

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am using the following line of code:

```
ListOfMyClass.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
             .Where(x => !x.Deleted).First();
```

And I get

> "Replace with single call to first warning"

Which I would prefer to do but cant work out how.

I want to be able to say for the item with the Latest datecreated and that is marked as not deleted.

Where's the best place to learn these kind of query's and what's the best way to solve this one as I prefer to be a tidy coder.

Comment: What is this: `Replace with single call to first warning` ? I doubt that this is the exact warning. Apart from that, what tool throws that warning?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I think this is a warning from ReSharper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call it without where:

```
ListOfMyClass.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).First(x => !x.Deleted);
```

`First` accepts predicates also. It really does not matter if you write `Where` and `First` in this case or just `First` it's evaluated to the same query at all :) But `First` looks cleaner.

As Jeroen van Langen said `Where` is slightly faster than `First`. So I assume that using `Where.OrderByDescending.First` is the best solution so far.

Comment: I thought it ment order by descending isnt required as you can pull the newest date value using first it was just how to do that i was stuck?

Comment: @LmC single call to first warning means that you can replace `Where.First` with just `First` :)

Comment: I wouldn't do the Where in the `First()`. Look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663897/why-is-linq-wherepredicate-first-faster-than-firstpredicate

Answer (score 5):

It's just a suggestion to use [the other overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050.aspx) of `First`, which accepts an inline predicate. This allows you to replace `.Where(...).First()` with just `.First(...)`:

```
ListOfMyClass.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).First(x => !x.Deleted);
```

That said, an even better way to write the query would be

```
ListOfMyClass.Where(x => !x.Deleted)
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
             .First();
```

Here the above "code-writing optimization" does not apply, but this version filters *before* sorting. This could speed up the sort substantially, depending on what percentage of items is filtered out. There really is no sense in sorting elements that you are just going to disregard.

Comment: I thought it ment order by descending isnt required as you can pull the newest date value using first it was just how to do that i was stuck?

Comment: @LmC: No, the order is required.

Comment: I think using the Where before ordering is the way to go. +1

Answer (score 2):

To 'satisfy' the warning you could rewrite it to:

```
ListOfMyClass.OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
             .First(x => !x.Deleted);
```

But I prefer to do filtering before sorting, so I'd use this:

```
ListOfMyClass
             .Where(x => !x.Deleted)
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
             .First();
```

Comment: Is there any benifit to filter before sorting

Comment: @LmC, ignore my previous statement. If this is Linq to objects (which I'm presuming it is) the ordering of the where, etc. is relevant [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6802942/542251)

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the `Where` first, so there are less items to sort.

```
ListOfMyClass.Where(x => !x.Deleted).OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated).First();
```

Also, you might want to use [MaxBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs) fom MoreLinq:

```
ListOfMyClass.Where(x => !x.Deleted).MaxBy(x => x.DateCreated);
```

Comment: @Liam I'm not sure. I would assume `OrderByDescending` reads all items and sorts them in O(nlogn).

Comment: I think it depends. If it's *Linq to Objects* your right, if it's *Linq to SQL* the lazy loading will create a single SQL statement and this will have no effect. I'm guessing this is Linq to objects so it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListOfMyClass.Where(x=> !x.Deleted).OrderByDescending(x=>x.DateCreated).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...the latest datecreated and that is marked as deleted...

If you want the latest, deleted item, why are you asking for non-deleted(`!x.Deleted`)?

I would suggest this:

```
var yourClassOrNull = ListOfMyClass
    .Where(x => x.Deleted)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateCreated)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is readable, safe and efficient. It is safe because `FirstOrDefault` returns the first item that matches the condition in the `Where` ordered by `OrderByDescending`. If no items match the condition the default value is returned, in case of reference types like here `null`. So you can check later `if(yourClassOrNull != null) ...`.

It is efficient since it's important to order after you have filtered in Linq-To-Objects.

Comment: I consider `OrderByDescending` followed by `First`(`OrDefault`) neither readable nor efficient. That's why there is a `MaxBy` extension method in MoreLinq.

Comment: @Henrik: It's as readable as sql is. And `MaxBy` is more efficient, but  it wansn't even clear if it's `Linq-To-Objects` at all and i've assumed that he wants an answer with .NET methods only. Also, if `.Where(x => x.Deleted)` retuns only few items it's not expensive to order them.